# color tree node with 2 colors but not through the user

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

I want to color on part of tree node but not through  the user (without using "selected node")
so DrawMode is not helping me.

I am using c#

For example I want that all tree nodes with space on the text will color in one side at green and the other side to red.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrawMode is the way to go. You have to set it to OwnerDrawText, and subscribe to the DrawNode event. I.e.:

```
this.treeView1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
this.treeView1.DrawNode += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(this.treeView1_DrawNode);
```

This is just a sample of how the drawing method could look like. It's up to you to modify it in order to have a good graphical result, but it can give you an idea of the way to go.

```
    private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        Font nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont;
        if (nodeFont == null) nodeFont = ((TreeView)sender).Font;

        string txt = e.Node.Text;
        int idx = txt.IndexOf(' ');
        string greenTxt;
        string redTxt;
        if (idx >= 0)
        {
            greenTxt = txt.Substring(0, idx);
            redTxt = txt.Substring(idx);
        }
        else
        {
            greenTxt = txt;
            redTxt = string.Empty;
        }
        Rectangle greenRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Location, new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(e.Graphics.MeasureString(greenTxt, nodeFont).Width), e.Bounds.Height));
        Rectangle redRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Location + new Size(greenRect.Width, 0), new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(e.Graphics.MeasureString(redTxt, nodeFont).Width), e.Bounds.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(greenTxt, nodeFont, Brushes.Green, greenRect);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(redTxt))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(redTxt, nodeFont,
                Brushes.Red, redRect);
    }
```

You can find a more complex example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx).

Comment: I have a problem with your code, when I expand the tree enrolled me at the top of the tree all I expands on one another and then I'm rolling it disappears
What do you say?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Maybe you could try to add a picture

Comment: When I expand node,it's child node appears on the top of the tree above the text that Exist. it's looking like 2 words one above the other.

Comment: You are specifying exactly where to draw the strings (the rectangle the string is contained in). I do not know what's happening here, but I'd take a look at the values of e.Bounds.Location

Comment: You posted this eight years ago, but it is still the most helpful code for a simple DrawNode method with OwnerDrawText that I have been able to find. Thank you.